# Locked question "Instruments that are easy on left pinkie fingers" would benefit from [physical-limitations] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The question [Instruments that are easy on left pinkie fingers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/39538/instruments-that-are-easy-on-left-pinkie-fingers) is currently (and appropriately) locked. Since it has enough value to be kept accessible, it would benefit from having the [physical-limitations](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-limitations) tag added to it.

Is this something a Mod can/would be willing to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag has been updated by moderator. Adding an answer just to make clear the question is resolved.